# How do I get EnvironmentName in Global.Application_Start

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an old (.NET 4.6.2) ASP.NET Web API and I would like to get the `EnvironmentName` in `Global.Application_Start` for logging purposes.

I can't seem to find a way to get `IHostEnvironment` in this old app. Was there some way in these older applications to get that information?

Comment: Don't think this exists in older non .net core ASP.net web applicaions and API's unfortunately